# html2canvas is not capturing true google map on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, html2canvas

I have created a google map application to capture view of map. The [working code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/nqqh9w3q/4/). I am using html2canvas tool for capturing.

```
var captureMap = function(){
   html2canvas(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),{
       "useCORS": true,
       "allowTaint": true, 
       "logging": true,
       "onrendered": function (canvas) {                  
              document.getElementById('canvas').innerHTML="";
              document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(canvas);
       }
      });
}
```

I can capture map image success with Mozilla Firefox and IE. But Chrome not working fine. Tiles are hidden when map move.

What is the problem of chrome?

Comment: Yes is possible but that duplicated question did not solve my problem.

Comment: but it does answer your question: "What is the problem of chrome?"